# How to make timePicker in Android Studio 3

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0, timepicker

I am very beginner in android development and i need somebody help for this question. I want to make an Alarm Manager (Simple alarm timer, for start), and i need to make a time picker. So, i want to make material time picker and get information from it. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time I suggest you search in google first, you can make a time picker dialog like this

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
              new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
              @Override
              public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {
                    txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                   }
              }, mHour, mMinute, false);
timePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank u very much, I`ll take your advise!